# DirectX Z-Buffer Issue

Tags: c#, xna, directx, managed-directx, zbuffer

Does anyone knows what might be causing the weird artifacts I am seeing in my C# Managed DirectX application.  Here is a screenshot of the problem I am having:

[image]

What you are looking at is some terrain with a flat plane under it.

- To the left you can see the plane *in front* of the terrain even though it shouldn't be visible (it is underneath)
- In the middle there is a transition stage where you see what i've been calling 'blinds'
- On the right it is displayed correctly

This must be a Z-Buffer issue but I have not been able to sort it out.  Has anyone else run into this same problem?  It is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called Z fighting and most likely your zmin of the projection matrix is too small.

Comment: Didn't think to change the z-min, implementing the change right now thanks

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't _exactly_ a `MinZ` problem but I wouldn't have got it sorted without you!